# Fastest method for counting the maximum number of unique values in deque

Tags: java, optimization, count, unique, deque

I'm trying to find the fastest way to count the maximum number of unique values in m-sized subarrays of a series of n integers taken from the console. Is there any way to further optimize this code? Thank's in advance, Alex

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Deque deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int m = in.nextInt();
        long count = 0, c = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) deque.addFirst(in.nextInt());
        count = deque.stream().distinct().count();
        for (int i = 0; i < n - m; i++) {
            count = Math.max(count, deque.stream().distinct().count());

            deque.removeLast();
            deque.addFirst(in.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only the maximum value is stored in the `count` variable so I don't think there is any extra logic needed

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, didn't read the code properly!

Answer (score 1):

This is *O(NM)* (assuming `distinct` is *O(M)*).  It should be possible to do this in *O(N)* by tracking the number of values with non-zero counts currently inside the window.

Pseudocode:

```
for (int i = M; i < N; i++) {
    counts[x[i-M]]--;
    if (counts[x[i-M]] == 0) {
        nonzero--;
    }

    if (counts[x[i]] == 0) {
        nonzero++;
    }
    counts[x[i]]++;

    maxNonzero = max(maxNonzero, nonzero);
}
```

Comment: There is only the small detail required. It is possible to do with relatively small numbers. This solution should be changed to additional `HashMap` structure for further optimization.